# Does "Module does NOT support fine-tuning" mean that it cannot be used for transfer learning?

Tags: tensorflow

Some modules on the Tensorflow hub say that they "do not support fine-tuning". I'm finding it difficult to use one for transfer learning but that is also due to my inexperience. But I just wanted to know if my attempts are just ultimately in vain anyway.

Example: https://tfhub.dev/google/openimages_v4/ssd/mobilenet_v2/1

This module does not support fine tuning, but can I still use it as a starting point to add new layers onto the end to look for new objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fine-tuning**, consists of unfreezing the entire model you obtained (or part of it), and re-training it on the new data with a very low learning rate. This can potentially achieve meaningful improvements, by incrementally adapting the pre-trained features to the new data.

So, simply it means, you can not retrain these models (unfreeze layers), but of course you can add your own layers at the end of these models and create your new model.

Read more [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/transfer_learning#fine-tuning).